# What does it mean when they say 'stateful'?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question over the matplotlib - pyplot tutorial, the link is [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)
I'm a native dutch speaker and can read standard english.
My question is not about an example that doesn't work, but about the text.
In the pyplot_tutorial chapter, working with multiple figures and axis, they use the words statefulness and stateful. I don't understand what they mean. We don't have a word for it in dutch. I did  a search on internet, but i didn't find anything. I think that stateful means complete, using all possibilities.

I hope that somebody has an answer for me.
I know that this isn't a question to ask here because it isn't about programming, but i don't know where else to ask it.

Comment: There's a somewhat good explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)). I haven't seen the word used anywhere else in the English language other than in the CS/programming world. Maybe someone in [english.se] would know better...

Comment: it is that matplotlib remembers the figures you plotted. unless you say `plt.close()` the figures you previously plotted are still in memory. This is not a big issue when you plot few images, but when running a loop and plotting many images, it will consume a lot of memory

Comment: i don't know about matplotlib, but usualy stateful means that some state is recorded, a kind of context that is implicit to current 'session'. i usualy understand stateful as opposite to stateless, where at each call / use you have to provide full context since it is not kept. this is a quick comment, if you can attach url of pyplot tutorial to confirm.

Answer (score 14):

In this context the difference is probably best understood by a simple plotting example.

First the stateful example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot([0,1], [1,0])
```

Then the stateless (or rather object-oriented approach):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
li = ax.plot([0,1], [1,0])
```

These carry out the same steps:

1. Create a figure object (`matplotlib.figure.Figure`)
2. Create a new plotting area object (`matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot`) and add it to the figure
3. Create a new line into the plotting area (`matplotlib.lines.Line2D`)

In the object-oriented form we do the operations above rather explicitly and take the object references into variables (`fig`, `ax`, `li`). The references are not lost in the stateful interface, either, but they are hidden somewhere within `matplotlib`.

This difference becomes evident, when we try to change some properties, e.g. the size of the figure. With the OO approach:

```
fig.set_size_inches([10, 8])
```

With the stateful approach we first need to find the figure. There is a function for that; `plt.gcf`. So:

```
plt.gcf().set_size_inches([10,8])
```

is almost the same thing. The 'almost' part becomes very important in the situation where we have more than one figure open at the same time. `plt.gcf` returns the 'current' figure, but it is quite difficult to tell which one is the current one.

The same situation repeats with axes or lines. If we want to adjust the x ticks of the plot, then:

```
ax.set_xticks([0,.5,1])
```

is quite straightforward. With the stateful approach it becomes:

```
plt.gca().set_xticks([0, .5, 1])
```

where `gca()` returns the 'current' axis. If you have several subplots, this becomes quite complicated.

So, the question is who is holding the objects. The stateful interface is just a thin wrapper on the object-oriented information. All the parameters are in the objects, and there are many objects in one plot (hundreds, even thousands).

One point of the stateful interface of `matplotlib` is that it is often used with `pylab` running in `IPython`. This gives the stateful interface plus some shortcuts with namespaces. Plotting a sinusoid is as easy as:

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100)
plot(x, sin(x))
```

This is arguably simpler than:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
li = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
```

But while the shortcuts provided by `pylab` are very handy with interactive work, it is not good in scripts. I use `pylab`, as well, but I show almost all examples in my `matplotlib` related answers in th eobject-oriented form because it is much more transparent.

Comment: A nice example, but this answer is partly incorrect: `matplotlib.pyplot.figure`, whilst appearing more OOP, still gives a *stateful* plot instance bound to `pyplot`. `matplotlib.figure.Figure` will return you your stateless version.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, state is akin to memory.

You can think of it using an analogy:

- A stateless person has no memory of their life from one task to the next.
- A stateful person has a memory/keeps track of their life from one task to the next.

In your case, stateless means values are be plotted without reference to past values.

By being stateful, the library keeps track of or remembers past values that are plotted.

This avoids excessive memory consumption and process overhead.